# Hyperledger composer "Unexpected response code 500" from android volley http post request

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to post data to hyperledger composer from android through volley http client library. below is code.

```
String url="http://50.23.0.202:31090/api/Doctor";
private void postUsingJson() throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue requstQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); // this = context
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put("$class", "org.acme.Doctor");
    jsonObject.put("doctorID", "300");
    jsonObject.put("doctorName", "Zubair ");
    jsonObject.put("contact", "05654");
    jsonObject.put("description", "Cardiologist");
    jsonObject.put("schedule", "resource:org.acme.Schedule#2");

    System.out.println("json "+jsonObject);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonobj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println("response "+response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("hi "+error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );
    jsonobj.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48,
            0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requstQueue.add(jsonobj);
}
```

[After running this code i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puh3f.jpg)

When I copy the same json(as given in picture above) and post it through composer rest server it works fine.

Comment: if getting 500 error code then it server side error and i also suggest used retrofit for api calling. it is easy and better to understand.

Comment: seems like something you are sending with this code cause an error server-side. I would suggest you switch to retrofit, but you can still get some informations with volley too. Since the server is correctly giving you a response when you call it outside this code, I guess the issue is in the json you send. Just change the volley's log level. You'll have to do this in your terminal: "adb -s DEVICE_ID shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE", where DEVICE_ID is the id of your attached device. Then, you'll see detailed informations on what you're sending to the server

Comment: it may be to do with the params passed in the JsonObjectRequest - would suggest to look at these two solutions both use @override to perform it correctly -> https://www.itworld.com/article/2702452/development/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-google-volley-on-android.html and Volley JSON POST example here -> http://www.zoftino.com/get-&-post-data-using-http-library-volley-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not too late. It looks like your business network already has a doctor whose doctorID is 300, so you can not add another user with the same doctorID because the doctorID has to be unique. Try to change the doctor's id to any other number that is not already on your network.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you solved this problem or not.
But sometimes, it is very useful to verify actual http packet using tool like Wireshark. You can compare packets between the cases of curl and application